# What does it mean when a player's damage meter is on fire?

Tags: multiversus

What does it mean when a fire appears behind a player's damage number during a match in MultiVersus?

[image: Fire behind opponent's damage meters]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flames appear behind a player's damage meter when they reach 100 or more damage. The flames increase in size as the player takes more damage.

Comment: on a side note, some perks activate when above 100 damage